# Fonts in Oracle Reports 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, fonts, barcode, oraclereports

I have a report with some arial fonts. Fonts looks correct on report build, but when report is generated by report server in PDF it doesnt apply the Arial Font. I have entries for font mapping in uifont.ali. Here are the contents of my uifont.ali.

```
[ PDF:Subset ]

Arial..Italic.Bold.. = "Arialbi.ttf"

Arial...Bold.. = "Arialbd.ttf"

Arial..Italic... = "Ariali.ttf"

Arial..... = "Arial.ttf"

*="ARIALUNI.TTF"
```

For some reason it only applying the * entry. If i change * entry to like

```
*="Arial.ttf"
```

Then it it apply Arial font.

Only * entry is applied. If i remove * entry it apply some device fonts.

TTF files are in Reports_Path

Answer (score 1):

For *uifont.ali* of Oracle Reports, there are two golden rules :

1. The *True Type font* files must exist in any one of the folders
    specified in *REPORTS_PATH*. (This case seems to be performed in the Question's text)
2. For a particular font (*Arial*, in this case), there are precedence
    rules for Reports in *PDF* format :

   - Entries in Font Subsetting( in `[ PDF:Subset ]` part )

     takes    precedence over

     the entries in Font Embedding( in `[ PDF:Embed ]` 
     part ) 
     (*No problem, this is not our case*).
   - Entries in Font Aliasing( in `[ PDF ]` part )

     takes precedence    over

     the entries in Font Subsetting( in `[ PDF:Subset ]` part )

     (***The problem may stem from this.*** *This should be inspected if there are entries for font arial in `[ PDF ]` part suppressing the ones in `[ PDF:Subset ]` part* ).